# Yii with bootstrap extension,Alias "bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am trying to use [bootstrap extension](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html) with yii but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title,i double checked my configuration file but I dont know where I am doing it wrong. Here is my `config/main.php`

```
    <?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
        'language'=>'en_us',
        'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'name'=>'CODEPAC',

        // preloading 'bootstrap,log' component
        'preload'=>array('bootstrap','log',),

        // autoloading model and component classes
        'import'=>array(
                'application.models.*',
                'application.components.*',

        ),

        'modules'=>array(
                // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
                'user'=>array(
                'debug'=>false,
                'userTable'=>'user',
                'translationTable'=>'translation',
                'mailer'=>'PHPMailer',
                'facebookConfig'=>array(
                        'appId'=>'12345',
                        'secret'=>'secret',
                        'domain'=>'localhost',
                        'status'=>true,
                        'xfbml'=>true,
                        'cookie'=>true,
                        'lang'=>'en_US',)
                ),
                 'avatar'=>array(),

                'profile' => array(
                'privacySettingTable' => 'privacysetting',
                'profileFieldTable' => 'profile_field',
                'profileTable' => 'profile',
                'profileCommentTable' => 'profile_comment',
                'profileVisitTable' => 'profile_visit',
                 ),
                 'role' => array(
                'roleTable' => 'role',
                'userRoleTable' => 'user_role',
                'actionTable' => 'action',
                'permissionTable' => 'permission',
                 ),

                'registration' => array(
                 ),


                'gii'=>array(
                        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
                        'password'=>'password',
                        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
                        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
                        'generatorPaths'=>array('bootstrap.gii',),
                ),

        ),

        // application components
        'components'=>array(
                'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',),
                'session'=>array(
                'sessionName'=>'SiteSession',
                'class'=>'CHttpSession',
'autoStart'=>true,
                ),
                 'cache'=>array('class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache'),
                        'user'=>array(
                        'class'=>'application.modules.user.components.YumWebUser',
                        // enable cookie-based authentication
                        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                         'loginUrl'=>array('//user/user/login'),
                ),
                // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

                'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        /*'rules'=>array(
                                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        ),*/
                ),
                /*
                'db'=>array(
                        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
                */


                'db'=>array(
                        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb',
                        'emulatePrepare' => true,
                        'username' => 'myDbUsername',
                        'password' => 'myDbPassword',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'tablePrefix'=>'',
                ),

                'errorHandler'=>array(
                        // use 'site/error' action to display errors

'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
                'log'=>array(
                        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                        'routes'=>array(
                                array(
                                        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                        'levels'=>'error, warning',
                                ),
                                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                                /*
                                array(
                                        'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                                ),
                                */
                        ),
                ),
        ),

        // application-level parameters that can be accessed
        // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
        'params'=>array(
                // this is used in contact page
                'adminEmail'=>'example@example.com',
        ),
        'import'=>array('application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',),
);
```

Comment: Did you copy the bootstrap extension to the protected/extensions/bootstrap directory and change the owner and permissions so it is readable?

Comment: @Spidaboy7 ... you should be more careful when pasting your config. Hide all your passwords and secret keys before you post them to a public website such as this one.

Comment: thanks Stu and Umair..i was so desperate that i didnt take my time to post it..i hope to not do the same mistake again,.. @Stephen305,yeah..i did change the permission on all files under bootstrap,and extensions is writable/readable too!i just cant figure out what its wrong!

Comment: @Spidaboy7 can you paste here the full path of `TbNavbar.php` inside bootstrap extension folder?

Comment: yeah,its protected/extensions/bootstrap/widgets/Tbnavbar.php

Comment: Hey,it had nothing with the configuration,i had an old version of Yii-boostrap that has Different class naming,Thx everyone though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii-Bootstrap is no longer preloaded, so now must use path alias.
Do this. Download the lastest version of yii-bootstrap.
In the first line of your main.php config paste:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
```

And configure the extension like this:

```
'components'=>array(
        [...]
    'bootstrap' => array(
                //'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'),
                'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'),
```

And you are done.

For more references, read this: http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you assign [read] access permission to extensions/bootstrap that you uncompressed.

If you are on Mac / Linux, execute:

chmod 755 bootstrap

On windows, right click on the folder, and assign read access to Apache's account. Sometimes assigning read access to "Everyone" is acceptable too (depending if you care about security or not, though).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I granted full(777) permission to the extension folder.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on my production server even though it worked fine locally.

The solution was to grant apache ownership to the yii installation:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/yourapp
```

previously ownership was root and apache couldn't see the files